# Who was Hans Bauer who worked on the Perron integral?

Tags: integration, math-history

I'm referring to the Hans Bauer who is the author of [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01999447) from 1915 (H. Bauer, Der Perronsche Integralbegriff und seine Beziehung auf Lebesguesschen, Monatsh. Math. Phys., 26 (1915), 153–198). When was this man born and when did he die? I'm asking because I have mentioned his name in the beginning of my thesis and I would like to provide the reader with some additional information.

Comment: Maybe https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask?

Comment: Google?? A google-books search for ["Hans Bauer" + math](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hans+Bauer%22+math&tbm=bks) shows someone with this name was a math tutor for Pauli, and a google search using a wildcard for the middle name --- ["Hans * Bauer" + Pauli](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hans+*+Bauer%22+Pauli) shows that the "Pauli" Bauer is Hans Adolf Bauer, who you can now easily find information about. As to whether this "Bauer" is your "Bauer", see whether the affiliation given in the paper you cited (not accessible to me) matches what you can find about the Pauli "Bauer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Books gives a couple of hits.  This is from "Promoting the Planck Club," (Donald W. Braben, 2014)

With his reading guided by Mach and expert intuition from Hans Bauer (1891–1953), a theoretical physicist, the young Pauli made impressive progress and almost incredibly made himself expert in Einstein's general relativity theory, keeping step ...

Also "The Historical Development of Quantum Theory" by Helmut Rechenberg has this footnote on page 378 of Volume 2:

[image]

The text mentions that he was Pauli's private tutor.